# How can we disable streaming mode of mp3 files on cloud flare?

Tags: cloudflare

I accidentally noticed that the URLs of mp3 files on my web site are acting like live streaming mode. When I turned the cloud flare off, then everything worked fine. I guess maybe the issue is due to something regarding the settings or sth else on cloudflare but I’m not sure yet. Any comment / help?

I have searched the cloudflare community to find any solution but I could not find any clue. The only URL I found is as the following:
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/mp3s-plays-like-live-stream/57090
that was another member who raised this question but no answer was there.

I need to know if there is any solution for my problem with the streaming of mp3 files on cloudflare.

Any comment / help?

Comment: While not 100% sure, it seems it has something to do with the HTTP headers being sent. You can try an experiment, comparing when the setting is OFF vs ON, and see there what is being sent that is different.